# Forward Declaration of class as template param. Why does this work?

Tags: c++

I have been playing around with some c++ template meta-programing and I have discovered situation which I think is rather peculiar. 
Let say I have the following class.

```
template<typename T>
class Foo{
};
```

Then later I found I use a foward declaration of a class (I am assuming that is what it is being treated as) as the template argument as so

```
Foo<class bar> bar1;
```

I also found that the following also compile fine.

```
Foo<class bar()> bar2;
Foo<class bar(int a)> bar3;
```

So my question is, why does this work. What is going on in all three cases.
According to the standard I can not declare a class at this point so this fails:

```
Foo<class bar{}> bar4
```

My original assumption was this just a forward declaration and you could actually declare a class at that pointer (which I could see possible uses for). 
However, you can not. So my second question what is the use of above? Is there any practical uses of it or is just a result of how c++ works that this is legal. One use I can see is you can use this to create tagging information on a type.

I am using the most recent version of g++

Comment: `Foo<class bar> f; class bar { };`.

Comment: Actually, `template<class bar> class Foo { };` can be read as declaring an invalid unnamed non-type template parameter of type `bar`. As far as I'm aware, there's no disambiguation rule for this in the spec :)

Comment: `Foo<class bar(int a)>` instantiates `Foo` with `T = bar(int)`, i.e. a function taking an `int` argument and returning `bar`. `class bar` is an "elaborate type specifier".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In all 3 cases, you are forward declaring the class `bar`, so you have to define it later one.

---

```
Foo<class bar> bar1;
```

This works because it is allowed to declare a class for the first time in a template argument, i.e. it is equivalent to

```
class bar;
Foo<bar> bar1;
```

---

```
Foo<class bar()> bar2;
```

This creates the class `bar`, just as before, and creates a function taking no parameters and returning a `bar`.

---

```
Foo<class bar(int a)> bar3;
```

This is really similar to the second one, just that here, it declares a function taking an `int`, instead of none. It is equivalent to

```
class bar;
Foo<bar(int)> bar3;
```

Answer (score 0):

The language expects a type in `Foo< ... >`. What you're providing is an "incomplete type" (`bar` isn't defined yet), but that's fine because `T` isn't actually used anywhere in your template.

C++ allows the syntax `class bar` to refer to a class `bar` for compatibility with C, where you had to say `struct bar` to refer to a type defined as `struct bar { ... };`. In C++, the `struct`/`class` keyword is optional if the compiler already knows that `bar` is a class.

`class bar()` and `class bar(int a)` are function types. They mean `bar ()` and `bar (int)` respectively, i.e. a function (taking no arguments / taking an `int`) returning a `bar`.